# Materials and AngularJS for a mostly-static site

Tags: angularjs

I like what Materials and Angular are doing.  I want to rewrite my site to have a nice navbar using that.  But I want a very few parts of my website to have SPA. I presume for most if it, there would not be a router, but for a few pieces of it, there would.

Is this design crazy?

Comment: The question you're asking's a bit broad...

Comment: no router on client side? only one page? then I don't see much benefit you can gain since initial load time is not impressive.

Comment: Well, I'll still have a framework for my breadcrumb buttons and maybe "search within this page" and so on.  Just wondering if anyone has built a mostly static site with Angular and Materials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about crazy, but I don't really see what you are trying to do. My only guess is you want to play with it, but don't want to re-write the entire site. As far as I understand it, the appeal of SPAs is the faster loading time (all html doesn't have to be resent, just the current view). It seems sharing data between views isn't necessary in your case, so I won't get into that.

In short, there is no real reason (except maybe time) not to stick all of the tab content into their own views instead of calling a new html page. So, you have your navbar on your index page (possibly as a directive), and under that you have the space for views (tab content).

This is a really simple question, and giving your rep I feel like I am missing something and saying the obvious, in which case I apologize.